# Как объявить глобальную переменную уровня проекта

Tags: c#, global-variables

При запуске программы я делаю запрос к базе и сохраняю данные в элемент List. 
Как мне сохранить данные, Чтобы я мог получить доступ из любого места в проекте. Я думал сохранить в txt потом считывать каждый раз, но это не есть хорошо) Подскажите правильный вариант

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Храните этот список в public static поле класса (какого - решите исходя из логики приложения).

Пример. Список будет храниться в статическом классе `ListStore` в свойстве `PublicList`. Заполнять будем методом этого же класса `InitList`.
На запуске программы вызываем этот самый `InitList`, после чего наш список сформирован и мы можем обращаться к нему через `ListStore.PublicList` (что мы и делаем в методе `GetFirstRecordFromList` класса `ListUser`)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal static class ListStore
    {
        public static List<string> PublicList { get; set; }

        public static void InitList()
        {
            PublicList = new List<string>();
            PublicList.Add("First");
            PublicList.Add("Second");
        }
    }

    public class ListUser
    {
        public string GetFirstRecordFromList()
        {
            return ListStore.PublicList.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListStore.InitList();
            var listUser = new ListUser();

            Console.WriteLine(listUser.GetFirstRecordFromList());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можно хотя бы пример)