# Как объявить глобальную переменную в c#?

Tags: c#

```
public class car
{
      public static int carmode;
      public static int fueltype;
      public static int rashod;
      public int bak;
      public static string ftype,cmode;
}

public class car95:car
{
     public car95(int CRM, int b)
     {
          bak = b;
          carmode = CRM;
          fueltype = 95;
          rashod = 10 + carmode;
     }

}
```

Когда создаю переменную auto не могу ее использовать. Подскажите, что нужно исправить.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (fuel == 95) { car95 auto = new car95(mode, 50); }
     if (fuel == 100) { cardt auto = new cardt(mode, 50); }
     if (fuel == 200) { cargas auto = new cargas(mode, 50); }

}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423074/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1

Comment: Вам наверняка не нужна "глобальная переменная". Покажите где вы хотите использовать переменную.

Comment: Но вряд ли Вам нужна глобальная переменная

Answer (score 7):

Основная ошибка -- если начали использовать объекты, то откажитесь от идеи использовать статичность и глобальность. Когда разберётесь с объектами, то поймёте где иногда нужна статичность. Так, что убирайте static из ваших классов (как оно вообще скомпилировалось?)

```
public class car
{
    public int carmode;
    public int fueltype;
    public int rashod;
    public int bak;
    public string ftype,cmode;
}

public class car95:car
{
    public car95(int CRM, int b)
    {
        bak = b;
        carmode = CRM;
        fueltype = 95;
        rashod = 10 + carmode;
    }

}
```

Вторая ошибка -- области видимости, у переменных они есть свои у каждой.

```
if (fuel == 95) { car95 auto = new car95(mode, 50); }
```

У переменной auto область видимости `{ car95 auto = new car95(mode, 50); }` и всё! Не ранее, не позднее к ней не обратиться.
Можно<sup>1</sup>, т.к. форма на которой у вас кнопка button1 это тоже объект, завести поле в форме.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private car auto;     

    ...
    ... 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fuel == 95) { auto = new car95(mode, 50); }
        if (fuel == 100) { auto = new cardt(mode, 50); }
        if (fuel == 200) { auto = new cargas(mode, 50); }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что для auto я поставил тип `car`, а не `car95` или иной. В этом третья ваша ошибка -- нельзя для одной переменной или поля назначить три разных типа. Но если все предполагаемые типы наследуются от одного общего, то можно назначить тип предка.

Ну и нельзя не упомянуть:

1. Реализация на форме логики, несвязанной с UI (интерфейс пользователя), не рекомендуется. Лучше отделять логику приложения от работы с UI. [Хабрахабр. Паттерны для новичков: MVC vs MVP vs MVVM](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215605/)
2. Хоть это и спорный момент, но всё-таки есть [Соглашения о написании кода на C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) , которые Ваш код и мои поправки нарушают.
3. Странно, что у Вас столько `int` используется. Попробуйте `enum` [Краткий обзор языка C#. Перечисления](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/enums)
4. Публичные поля тоже не рекомендуется использовать, когда разберётесь используйте публичные свойства вместо них. [Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0?noredirect=1&lq=1)
5. А здесь ([Как объявить глобальную переменную уровня проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423074/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0?noredirect=1&lq=1)) есть ответ про глобальные переменные.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, использовать глобальные переменные не желательно.
Всё таки, я бы порекомендовал пересмотреть дизайн вашего приложения.
Но если уж очень хочется - то можно оформить переменные в виде
статических полей статического класса. Технически - это глобальные переменные.
Только обращаться к ним нужно через имя класса.
И мне кажется, судя по приведённому коду, лучше расположить переменные
в том же классе, где и объявлен обработчик нажатия кнопки.