# Как запретить открытие формы с данными, если она уже отрыта другими

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть список с данными. Нажимая 2 раза, открывается форма с этими детальными данными. Там есть идентификационный код или серия. Нужно запретить, открытие формы по идентификационному коду если она уже открыта.

Возможно ли это?

Comment: может лучше просто открывать форму детальных данных как единственно доступную поверх основного списка данных, типа `formDetails.ShowDialog();` ?

Comment: Самый простой способ, если бизнес-логика согласна, то это модальное диалоговое окно. Если бизнес-логика требует многооконного интерфейса, создать список строк-идентификаторов серий в родительской форме. Соответственно при открытии - проверять нет ли там уже этой серии. А при закрытии onClose() удалять из этого списка родительской формы соответствующий идентификатор.

Comment: Можно в публичном свойстве окна с данными возвращать ваш идентификатор, и перед открытием проверять нет ли открытой формы с таким идентификатором, если нет, открываем новую, если есть выводим на передний план уже открытую. Можно объединить с вариантом Александра.

Comment: коллега  rdorn прав, у родительской формы уже есть список потомков, а поэтому серию лучше привязать к форме, и при двойном клике проверять, есть ли форма с такой серией, и если есть - выводить на передний план.

Answer (score 1):

Просто блокировать открытие не хорошо, т.к. это может быть неправильно понято конечным пользователем и увеличит число обращений в тех.поддержку.

В любом случае, вам понадобится как-то опознавать с какими именно данными открыта форма/окно/контлол. Для этого нужно добавить публичное свойство, в котором будет возвращаться идентификатор для опознавания.

Далее можно использовать такой вариант:

- При открытии форма регистрируется в словаре как открытая, с идентификатором в качестве ключа. (в этом месте возможны варианты в реализации, например использовать список дочерних форм, регистрация в котором происходит автоматически при открытии, но суть от этого не меняется)
- Перед открытием новой проверяем, зарегистрирована ли форма в открытых.
- Если зарегистрирована - выводим на передний план, если нет - создаем новую, регистрируем, открываем.
- При закрытии удаляем регистрацию.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно!

Принцип прост, нужен статичный Бул, при открытий нужного окна вы проверяете его состояние, если `false` делаете его  `true` и открываете форму, ну а если он `True` то выводите сообщение, а при закрытий формы делаете обратно в `false` .

Надеюсь понятно что `true` - означает форма открыта и `false` - форма закрыта.

Comment: В этом варианте вы не сможете открыть две формы с разными данными, а этого запрещать не требовалось. Но для случая, когда в принципе не должно быть открыто более одного экземпляра, идеально подходят модальные окна.

Comment: Вроде про 2 и более форм ничего не говорилось, да и вопрос не про то как открыти простую форму!

Comment: Даже в этом случае обычное модальное (диалоговое) окно уже реализует необходимый функционал без необходимости писать что-то от себя. Даже исходную форму менять не нужно, просто правильно открыть.

Comment: Да конечно он может использовать модальное окно. Но вопрос был не про то как создать эту форму и где а про другое, вот прочтите вопрос и поймете

Answer (score 0):

Определяем глобальный переменную список куда будем сохранять при открытии формы код и при закрытии удалять оттуда код.

```
internal static class GlobabalModule
{
    public static List<string> CodeList { get; set; }

    public static void InitList()
    {
        CodeList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

[Как объявить глобальную переменную уровня проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423074/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)